# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Android when declaring array

Tags: java, android

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
        "/images/make_machine_example.jpg");    
int[] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth()*bm.getHeight()];           
_i.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I seem to be getting the error at the pixels array declaration.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the JPEG?  Are they huge?  How are you testing? On a device or with the emulator?  If the latter, did you give the virtual device plenty of RAM?

Comment: I am using an android device. I looked at the image and its around 800kb and about 1900x2600 pixels.

Comment: Resize your image, then go for multi-dimensional array in your case int[][] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth()][bm.getHeight()];

Comment: That image is 19MB.  File size is irrelevant.  Default memory usage is 4 bytes per pixel so 1900x2600x4.   You must scale it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your bitmap's width and/or height is too big. Try scaling the bitmap until the exception goes away. Use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. But does scaling the bitmap pixelate the image?

Comment: You are making the bitmap smaller, so the quality should not become lower. However, for better results, make sure you set filter to true.

Answer (score 0):

Scale your Bitmap to the Phones' Display Dimension, i guess the original image is to big, so you'll get the OutOfMemoryException.

Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() will be your friend.

Comment: createScaledBitmap worked but is there a way where I can preserve the pixels? I need to process the image and i am afraid that it will cause less accuracy.

Comment: Have look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html, there it is explained how you process an image out of the UI Thread, so the app main thread would not stop and wait for completion of imageprocessing.